How to increase trigger voltage level (with zener and small RC values)?
I am using a MIC5014 to delay-start powering a load.
I want to give it a delay of power-on of about 2 seconds.
I see that Vin threshold to turn on is ~1V.

The limitation I am thinking of, is that I want to avoid using >100k resistors and large(r) capacitor for the RC circuit because the Capacitor leakage might start to matter after using 100k for the RC. At >100k I might be too dependent on the capacitor leakage which might get larger due to flux residue if soldering is done by hand. So the below schematic is the default which I want to avoid (with or without R2):

Before moving into using a Microcontroller to measure time instead, I would like to know if there is a way of raising the trigger voltage of the Input pin (~1V).
Here is what I came up with:

As the capacitor charges slow, the 20V zener does not let the voltage reach the Input pin. The 40k resistor after the zener helps not letting the pin floating and maintain the 0V of the right leg of the zener.
Once voltage at the RC reaches 20V, the Zener finally opens and then the Input pin is triggered.
At the simulation the trigger/Zener breakdown takes ~2 seconds to happen.
I was inspired to use the zener there because of Kaz's reply to another question here. I am wondering if I could use a transistor in this configuration as well. the transistors used on Kaz's answer the Zener is tied to the GND directly and not at a high impedance input like my case.

Is there any other way to increase input trigger voltage of a device without large RC values?
Do the simulations make sense? Maybe there is something that wont work in a real PCB, I do not use a professional simulator here after all.


Why not use an additional IC to generate the timing delay? It'd be simple to do with a tiny microcontroller, or a dedicated timer chip like an LTC6995. You could even do it with a 555-style timer, if you have power to spare.

Although I can't see any reason why this zener circuit wouldn't work. I'll let someone with more time to analyze it properly verify that, though--there may be some weird edge case that could cause premature turn-on from diode capacitance or something.

@Hearth I was looking at the 555 scenario. But looks like monostable configuration gets triggered at 0V only. Would that be enough and possible to create my timer delay? A 555 schematic suggestion would be the best next approach I guess. Id accept it as an answer

One problem with any circuit that does not use a Schmitt trigger to square-up the output to the MOSGET gate driver chip is that the rise/fall times may not be compatible with the MOSFET gate driver.  Many logic gates have a maximum rise/fall time specification that must not be exceeded; if the input is too slow the gate can be damaged.  This topic is discussed in detail here:
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scba004e/scba004e.pdf
Title: "Implications of Slow or Floating CMOS Inputs"
The datasheet of the MIC5014 does not mention this parameter, and the block diagram does not show the input as a Schmitt (refer image below), so I would be cautious about making any assumptions.

Link for image above:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC5014-5-Low-or-High-Side-MOSFET-Drivers-DS20006767.pdf
Have you considered using a power supervisor?  There are many to choose from, here is just one example from Onsemi:

Link for image above:
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp302-d.pdf
Add a capacitor to pin 5 (Cd) to adjust the delay time.
Note: the above chip is not my solid recommendation, this is meant as an illustration only, as there are too many to choose from and you need to consider other system requirements that we may not be aware of.
If you decide to go down this path, then I suggest using two power supervisors: one to monitor the state of the 24V supply, the other to provide the time delay to the MOSFET gate driver.  You can get single chips that contain 2 (or more) supervisors, eg: MIC2774L-46BM5.
Almost all such chips will require the 24V to be reduced, say, to 10 or 12V maximum, but they only draw a few uA so the resistor divider can be very high impedance.
The other benefit of this approach is that most power supervisors can be configured to turn off the MOSFET when the 24V supply falls to a user-defined level.

The first idea I have that comes to mind:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This should get you close to the timing you want.
Or if you want to get fancier, LT3092 is a configurable current source:

simulate this circuit
The advantage here is the time is independent of supply voltage. Since the last two circuits are the advanced versions, I'll leave it up to you to calculate resistor and capacitor values. If not, I suppose I could do the math.

Right, interesting. What is VCC voltage on your schematics? I cant understand what D2(clamp) does.

@ChristianidisVasilis Not needed. I wrongfully assumed your IC VCC was 3.3V or 5V powered. So the idea was to keep the voltage at pin 2 within a diode drop of VCC (chip power). Since your gate driver operates at 24V, it is unnecessary here. If you include it, it doesn't do anything.

Thank you. Both answers were very useful :)
